# Jquery not working with meteorjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I'm going through the first example of "Meteor in Action" [book](http://www.meteorinaction.com/) (myfridge app).
At the last step where we add drag and drop functionality for products, it seems that jquery is not recognized by my app. I chose the latest versions as the book is a little outdated.

I have included jquery CDNs as required in `/client/main.html` file

```
<head>
  <title>myfridge</title>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

And in my `/client/main.js` I have included the necessary declarations for making `fridge` and `productList` droppable and `productListItem` draggable.

```
Template.fridge.onRendered( function () {
    var templateInstance = this;

    templateInstance.$('#fridge').droppable({
        drop: function(evt, ui) {
            var query = { _id: ui.draggable.data('id') };
            var changes = { $set: { place: 'fridge' } };
            Products.update(query, changes);
        }
    });
});


Template.productList.onRendered( function() {
    var templateInstance = this;

    templateInstance.$('#supermarket').droppable({
        drop: function(evt, ui) {
            var query = { _id: ui.draggable.data('id') };
            var changes = { $set: { place: 'supermarket'} };
            Products.update(query, changes);
        }
    });
});

Template.productListItem.onRendered( function() {
    var templateInstance = this;

    templateInstance.$('.draggable').draggable({
        cursor: 'move',
        helper: 'clone'
    });
});
```

I've checked other posts with similar issues but it seems that the tips don't work for me.

**EDIT**: Error messages in console are

```
Exception from Tracker afterFlush function:
debug.js:41 TypeError: templateInstance.$(...).droppable is not a function
    at .<anonymous> (main.js:9)
    at template.js:119
    at Function.Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc (template.js:465)
    at fireCallbacks (template.js:115)
    at .<anonymous> (template.js:208)
    at view.js:107
    at Object.Blaze._withCurrentView (view.js:538)
    at view.js:106
    at Object.Tracker._runFlush (tracker.js:511)
    at onGlobalMessage (setimmediate.js:102)
debug.js:41 Exception from Tracker afterFlush function:
debug.js:41 TypeError: templateInstance.$(...).droppable is not a function
    at .<anonymous> (main.js:22)
    at template.js:119
    at Function.Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc (template.js:465)
    at fireCallbacks (template.js:115)
    at .<anonymous> (template.js:208)
    at view.js:107
    at Object.Blaze._withCurrentView (view.js:538)
    at view.js:106
    at Object.Tracker._runFlush (tracker.js:511)
    at onGlobalMessage (setimmediate.js:102)
debug.js:41 Exception from Tracker afterFlush function:
debug.js:41 TypeError: templateInstance.$(...).draggable is not a function
    at .<anonymous> (main.js:34)
    at template.js:119
    at Function.Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc (template.js:465)
    at fireCallbacks (template.js:115)
    at .<anonymous> (template.js:208)
    at view.js:107
    at Object.Blaze._withCurrentView (view.js:538)
    at view.js:106
    at Object.Tracker._runFlush (tracker.js:511)
    at onGlobalMessage (setimmediate.js:102)
debug.js:41 Exception from Tracker afterFlush function:
debug.js:41 TypeError: templateInstance.$(...).draggable is not a function
    at .<anonymous> (main.js:34)
    at template.js:119
    at Function.Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc (template.js:465)
    at fireCallbacks (template.js:115)
    at .<anonymous> (template.js:208)
    at view.js:107
    at Object.Blaze._withCurrentView (view.js:538)
    at view.js:106
    at Object.Tracker._runFlush (tracker.js:511)
    at onGlobalMessage (setimmediate.js:102)
```

Comment: hi what is your error msg ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error message is `templateInstance.$(...).droppable is not a function` which means your `client/main.js` does not have access to the `.droppable()` method made accessible by jQuery UI.

If all you need is the jQuery UI draggable and droppable functionality, you can install [drewproud:jquery-ui-droppable](https://atmospherejs.com/drewproud/jquery-ui-droppable) with `meteor add drewproud:jquery-ui-droppable`.

Comment: This seems to solve the issue. Although now when i drag and drop an item into the "fridge" the console pops a somewhat internal error of this wrapper `drewproud_jquery-ui-droppable.js:1725 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined`. Nevertheless, the code works as expected.

Answer (score -1):

Jquery is available as a meteor package

Include it like this:

```
meteor add jquery
```

Comment: I included it (and removed the <script> tags from html file) and the problem is still there.

Comment: The issue is with jQuery UI not being available, not jQuery. One does not need to `add` jquery to meteor as it comes pre-packaged as a hard dependency on all MeteorJS applications.